# How to make SQL return Boolean true/false (Not String) instead of 1/0

Tags: sql, postgresql

As titled, `CAST AS BIT` does not work, the returned value is still 1/0...  
`CASE WHEN ... THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as ...` does not work either, the returned value type is string instead of Boolean

E.g., C1 is Bool, C2 is Text

```sql
SELECT T.C1 FROM T WHERE T.C2 = 'text'
```

returns true, while

```sql
SELECT 3 > 0 AS C1 FROM T WHERE T.C2 = 'text'
```

returns 1

Comment: This question is very incomplete.  Please add the RDMS, query, datatype of field, and why values of 0 or 1 are perceived to be strings.

Comment: I think you are confused.  The return value of 1 or 0 *is* a BIT which *is* how a Boolean is stored.  The representation of `True` and `False` is a way to interpret a bit field and is handled by the GUI.

Comment: @DanBracuk I use PostgreSQL, the query is like:
      "SELECT CASE WHEN exp1 THEN v1 ELSE NULL END AS val"...

v1 is bool, while val is 0/1

Comment: If you are using a database that complies with the SQL standard, then `boolean` **is** already limited to `true` and `false`. It sounds as if your DBMS product does not properly support `boolean` types. So which DBMS **are** you using?

Comment: @GMan80013: no that's wrong. The SQL standard clearly defines that a boolean is `true` or `false`. A `bit` is something different then a `boolean` (in standard SQL - and that's what the tag `sql` refers to, not some specific DBMS product)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL... Actually I can handle the type issue somewhere else by parsing the string and get bool, but just curious if there is any other approach

Comment: You need to provide more information. What kind of expression are you  casting? A boolean expression **will** return `true` or `false` (as a boolean, not as a string), e.g. `select 42 > 0` will return `true`

Comment: @GMan80013 I really don't understand, why bool is stored as BIT?

Comment: Boolean is **not** stored as bit - at least not if the column is declared as `boolean`. Show us the **complete** code you are using including the table definitions as `create table` statements as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please.  **[Edit]** your question, do **not** post code as comments.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried that, still returned 1

Comment: Again: you need to provide the **complete** code you are using. Otherwise this question will be closed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
SELECT 42>0 AS val FROM t WHERE a=b

Comment: Again: [edit] your question. Do **not** post code in comments. And provide the definition of your tables as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: See [here](https://imgur.com/kzWDGPQ)  and [here](https://imgur.com/xlq8qG4). No `0` or `1` in the result

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a "Boolean" type in MySQL, however, there is in other forms of SQL. It is still shown as a 0 or 1 though, even in non-MySQL versions of SQL. If you are concerned with how it is displayed to you, then the string(varchar) form is the way to go.

Comment: DBMS that support a proper boolean will show them as true/false, not as 0/1